# Objects into two bags puzzle

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, algorithms, puzzle

I found a maths puzzle somewhere and a part of it as below:

Kelly wants to place n objects $a_1,a_2,⋅⋅⋅,a_n$ into **two** bags.
For each $i=1,2,⋅⋅⋅,n$, the weight of $a_i$ is $w_i$ kilograms.

The capacity of each bag is not a problem as it is not limited.

Kelly wants to minimize the weight of the most heavy bag. So this is what she does:

She ordered in an arbitrary order.
She always places the object under consideration into the least heavy bag.

**At the end when all objects are in the bags, Kelly finds that the weight of the most heavy bag is at most 3/2 times the optimum.**

How? ? ? How can she get to know that?

Extended version of [Weights - Objects into bags puzzle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1064906/weights-objects-into-bags-puzzle/1065261#1065261).

Any examples would make me understand better.Can we deduce a formula for such cases?

Comment: Where is this question from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let the sum of weights be $2s+m$ and let $m$ be the weight of the heaviest bag, then the heaviest the heavier side can get with the proposed method is $s+m$.

On the other hand the heavier side will always weight at least $\frac{2s+m}{2}$.

So we get the ratio of the heavy bag over the optimum is at most $\dfrac{s+m}{\frac{2s+m}{2}}=\dfrac{2s+2m}{2s+m}=1+\frac{m}{2s+m}$.

if $m$ is less than half of the total weight we are done, if $m$ is more than half of the total weight the optimum is clearly when $m$ is alone in the bag. And the worst case scenario is when the heavier bag has $m+s$ and the other side $s$. In this case the ratio of the worst case vs the optimum is $\frac{s+m}{m}=1+\frac{s}{m}$ which is less than $1+\frac{1}{2}$ since $m$ is at least twice as $s$ in this case.

Comment: what is **$s$** here?

Comment: We denotes by $2s+m$ the total weight of the objects and by $m$ the heaviest object, so I guess $s$ is half of the weight of all objects except the heaviest.

Comment: Also, I didn't understand, what do you meant by "In this case the ratio of the worst case vs the actual" ...what is actual?

Comment: sorry it should say optimal.

Comment: Do you understand it now, please feel free to tell me if something is not clear.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jorge. Now I understood.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

- Use exactly the same reasoning as in [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1065016/26306) to your previous question, just devise a stronger inequality.
- When adding an item of weight $w$, the weight of the bag with the smallest load is at most $$\frac{2M-w}{2}.$$

I hope that helps $\ddot\smile$